# col-md-8 shown in other line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use a `col-md-4` and a `col-md-8` , on the same line  but the `col-md-8` is placed down the `col-md-4` ,I tried without the form-control class with the same result

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 option-container ">
            <select id="tables" class="form-control">
                <option value="-1" disabled selected>Selecciona una tabla</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($tables as $table){
                        echo "<option>".$table."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
                    test text
        </div>
```

I don't know what is wrong

Comment: You forgot wrap the `.col-*` classes inside `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class="row"` after `container` class and close before container class.

Comment: `container` is closed,but didn't copy the whole code, using row it works, but I though that col-md-4 and a col-md-8 its a 12 witdh column and it should be shown on a the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding div element with row class

```
<div class="container">
   **<div class="row">**
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 option-container ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) uses a series of **containers**, **rows**, and **columns** to layout and align content.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <!-- REQUIRED element -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In your code** `.row` **element is missing.**

Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.